# Issue with "contains" hashset method (Java)

Tags: java, set, contains, hashset

The following code is not giving me the result I'm expecting:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    Set<Pair> objPair = new LinkedHashSet<Pair>();
    objPair.add(new Pair(1, 0));

    System.out.println("Does the pair (1, 0) exists already? "+objPair.contains(new Pair(1, 0)));

}

private static class Pair {

    private int source;
    private int target;

    public Pair(int source, int target) {
      this.source = source;
      this.target = target;
    }        
}
```

The result will be:

```
Does the pair (1, 0) exists already? false
```

I can't understand why it's not working.
Or maybe I'm using the "contains" method wrong (or for the wrong reasons).

There is also another issue,
if I add the same value twice, it will be accepted, even being a set

```
objPair.add(new Pair(1, 0));
objPair.add(new Pair(1, 0));
```

It won't accept/recognize the class Pair I've created?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `HashSet` works with hash codes. Where is your `hashCode()` implementation?

Comment: Ohh yes, I'm new at this, I probably need to study more about it :) thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your own hashCode() implementation, **Java considers two `Pair` objects equal only if they are the exact same object** and `new`, by definition, always creates a 'new' object. In your case, you want `Pair` objects to be consider equal if they have the same values for `source` and `target` -- to do this, you need to tell Java how it should test `Pair` objects for equality. (and to make hash maps work the way you expect, you also need to generate a hash code that is *consistent with equals* -- loosely speaking, that means equal objects **must** generate the same hashCode, and unequal objects **should** generate different hash codes.

Most IDEs will generate decent hashcode() and equals() methods for you. Mine generated this:

```
  @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      int hash = 3;
      hash = 47 * hash + this.source;
      hash = 47 * hash + this.target;
      return hash;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj == null) {
         return false;
      }
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
         return false;
      }
      final Pair other = (Pair) obj;
      if (this.source != other.source) {
         return false;
      }
      if (this.target != other.target) {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
```

Comment: Can't believe it was "only" this :) guess I forgot to mention I'm new at Java (you guys noticed though...) Thank you very much!

Comment: We were all new once…. :)

Comment: @NyanMaru recommended reading if you will be doing a lot of Java: http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683/ -- Item 9 in this books covers `hashCode` and `equals` -- I reread this book every few years and learn something new each time, bought the second edition when it came out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to override your `hashCode` and `equals` methods in your `Pair` class.  `LinkedHashSet` (and other Java objects that use hash codes) will use them to locate and find your `Pair` objects.